# Powershell - modify items in ZIP archive

Tags: powershell, zip

I read about extracting ZIP archives on *Stackoverflow* which results in creating following script:

```
$shell_app=New-Object -com shell.application

Get-ChildItem -name *.zip | ForEach-Object {
$zip_file=$shell_app.NameSpace((Get-Location).path + " \$_")
$destination=$shell_app.NameSpace((Get-Location).path)
$destination.copyhere($zip_file.items())  }
```

Now I'm interested in manipulating on items in this archive - for example before I unpack all those files, I want to add to their filenames, name of archive.
AS I check, I can get it (with .zip extenston which I want to remove) by simply entering

> %zip_file.title

but I'm not aware how to modify file names. Could anybody help or give sufficient resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with the shell object alone. I think you'll have to extract the file files and then rename using PowerShell. Here's my test code that works. Quick and dirty but it does the trick.

```
$zip="c:\work\brain.zip"
$shell_app=New-Object -com shell.application

$zip_file=$shell_app.NameSpace($zip)
$destination=$shell_app.NameSpace("G:\test")
$zip_file.items() | foreach {
  $newname="{0}_{1}" -f $zip_file.Title,$_.name
  Write-Host "Extracting $newname" -ForegroundColor Green
  $destination.copyhere($_)
  $oldfile=Join-path $destination.Self.Path -ChildPath $_.name
  Rename-Item -Path $oldfile -NewName $newname -passthru

}
```

Why not create a subfolder for each zipfile in the destination?